# How can i pass a variable into action attribute for download (button/link) using HTML or javascript,

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

```
<xsl:template name ="DLFiles">
  <xsl:variable name ="FilePath" select="@FilePath"/>    
  <form method="get" action="$FilePath">
        <button type="submit">Download</button>
```

(FilePath comes from a SQL column)

when $FilePath is a hardcoded (local) file path, this works great. However when a variable is passed, the download  does not work (the file path can not be found, cant get data(FilePath column data) from SQL)

is there something I can change in the above code to make this work correctly in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here if you want to use a variable in an attribute

```
 <form method="get" action="{$FilePath}">
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.